# Saving Separate worksheets of an Excel workbook as PDFs

Tags: excel, pdf, worksheet, vba

I have code that will save all of the worksheets in my workbook into a specific folder on my desktop, and this works, but when I changed the save destination to a folder in my network drive, the code stopped working. No error comes up, but the files are not saved in the folder.

Here is my code:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    strPDFName = ws.Name
    strDir = "SAVEFOLDER"
    ChDir strDir
    fileSaveName = ws.Name
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fileSaveName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Next ws
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use `ChDir` when you can do this instead?

```
fileSaveName = strDir & "\" & ws.Name
```

`ChDir` will change your working directory but what you really want is to specify the full path for your pdf file by concatenating the directory and the file name (I added a backslash between them because I assumed your `strDir` doesn't have one at the end).